# How to copy GitHub repository SSH URL in web browser using a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, git, google-chrome-extensions, github

GitHub repository SSH url:

```
git@github.com:user/repo.git
```

I am using Chrome  on Windows 10 and clone a lot of repositories from GitHub and having to click "Code" button then copy the url is not convenient.

What I am looking for is a keyboard shortcut that that whenever I go to GitHub repository and upon using that shortcut key, the GitHub SSH url should be copied to clipboard.

My guess is Chrome extension or userscript could help.

Comment: I don't know that there's an easy way to do what you want to do, but of course you could write your own extension or user script.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not exactly what you've asked for, but one option could be to configure Git to use SSH for GitHub even if you've specified a HTTPS URL. That way, you can easily copy the repo's URL from Chrome's navigation bar with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, and paste that straight in your `git clone`.

```bsh
git config --global url.git@github.com:.insteadof https://github.com/
```

Example:

```
➜ git clone https://github.com/greensync/omniauth-dex-energy      
Cloning into 'omniauth-dex-energy'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 160, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (160/160), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (85/85), done.
remote: Total 160 (delta 59), reused 131 (delta 43), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (160/160), 26.16 KiB | 13.08 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (59/59), done.

➜ cd omniauth-dex-energy 

➜ git config -l | grep github
url.git@github.com:.insteadof=https://github.com/
remote.origin.url=https://github.com/greensync/omniauth-dex-energy

➜ git remote get-url origin
git@github.com:greensync/omniauth-dex-energy
```